# how to split string using multichar string as delimiter in vba (excel)

Tags: excel, string, vba, split, delimiter

Please tell me how to split a string into parts, using as a separator a multichar string, not a single symbol

for example

```
array = MySplit("xdatayydatazzz", "data");
```

and result

```
array(0) = "x"
array(1) = "yy"
array(2) = "zzz"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Um, why not just use:

```
arr = Split("xdatayydatazzz", "data")
```

Just to be sure, I tested this, and it works as expected. Docs on Split [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f(v=vs.90).aspx).

Comment: you could not have tested it in VBA. the variable name `array` is illegal. the semicolon at the end of line is also illegal

Comment: It does work though. I wondered if it did, so thanks for checking!

Comment: Haha, true, I just tested the concept, not the exact spelling, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 3):

First do a replace on the string e.g. data with a chosen character e.g. @ and then  split on that:

```
secondstring = Replace("xdatayydatazzz", "data", "@")

array = Split(secondstring, "@")
```

Could nest the Replace inside the Split to keep to one step.